# li list positioning behavior

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/aUYTt/

I'm trying to figure out why the third level ul tag list in this jsfiddle example it squashed up at the same position as the second level ul
The second level li tags are positioned correctly but the third level get messed up any ideas why. 
Does position absolute crush the default list hierarchy positioning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
#nav ul{
    position:absolute;
}
```

which counts for all `<ul>` inside `#nav`, so even in the third or fifth level.

Re-style the third level separatly:

```
#nav ul ul {
    position: static;
}
```

See also: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position

Comment: I thought it had to do with this. But what I'm not understanding is I haven't set a position to the absolute ul tags. I thought when you set absolute it brings the tag outside of the normal flow but keeps the same position until you set a position for it. In this case relative to its parent. So why does the second level ul hold its position and the third does not.

Comment: @Chapsterj "I thought when you set absolute it brings the tag outside of the normal flow but keeps the same position until you set a position for it" That effect may be achieved by using `position: relative;`

Comment: Ok sorry I understand that. What I'm asking is why exactly in my jsfiddle example does the second level ul stay positioned correctly but the third level ul does not, instead it is at the same top position as the second level ul bottom li tag. Even though both are set to be absolute positioning. You pointed out the problem but I'm not sure what the reasoning behind it is.

Comment: IT IS positioned correctly! A `position: absolute;` without specifying dimensions means, place the element at 0px|0px measured from the last (relative|fixed|absolute) positioned parent element, which is the <li> with the <a href="#">Business Hours</a> inside.

Comment: Are you saying its positioned 0,0 to the parent. If so then it would be at the top corner of where the contact is. And that's not where it is right now. I did an update in jsfiddle to show what 0,0 position would be. http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/aUYTt/3/

Comment: @chapsterj - I think you are getting confused. First you set a rule of `position:absolute` on all `<ul>`s inside the `<ul id="nav">`. However the parent of the `<ul>` in question (the one that you consider misplaced) is the `<li>` that it was placed in inside your html. The parent refers to the element 1 up that it is contained inside.

Comment: Ok so this is the parent. <li>
                 <a href="#">Business Hours</a> so it should be positioned in the same position it was originally at inside the above li. not at the 0,0 position like you suggested above right. Now what I don't get is why it gets positioned on top of li Directions. Instead of below it.

Comment: From your comments then Week Days and Weekends should be overlapping Business Hours. as that's its parent and then Business hours should be overlapping Contact as that's its parent. But its not doing that so I'm totally confused by your comments sorry.